# How to specify an entityGraph with a namedNativeQuery?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to set a namedEntityGraph when using a NamedNativeQuery?

I am fetching the User entity as follows:

```
try {
    return (User) em.createNamedQuery("OAuthToken.getUser")
            .setParameter("token", accessToken)
            .setParameter("expirationInterval", expirationInterval)
            .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", "User.withProjectsMemberOf")
            .getSingleResult();
} catch (NoResultException e) {
    return null;
}
```

entityGraph:

```
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.withProjectsMemberOf",
            attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("projectsMemberOf")),
})
```

However I am getting the following warning:

The javax.persistence.fetchgraph hint was set, but the value was not an EntityGraph!

So is it possible to set the entity graph with a named native query?

I am currently setting the user for the current REST request in a filter. I would like to be able to dynamically fetch an entityGraph for the user based off of the annotation present on the matched resource method.

I am using spring-data-jpa, hibernate, and jersey

Comment: You specified the name of your entity graph as "User.withProjectsMemberOf", yet referred to the fetchgraph as "User.withMemberProjects".

Comment: @NeilStockton good catch, but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the `EntityGraph`, like this

```
EntityGraph myEG = em.getEntityGraph("User.withProjectsMemberOf");
```

and then set the fetchgraph, like this

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", myEG);
```

Comment: that fixed the warning, however now I am getting: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.    Any ideas?

Comment: Post your actual code and stack trace where that came from. If it was for a standard JPA API call and Hibernate threw that then it is a bug in your JPA provider and you should raise a bug on them